# How to remove table row on click in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

This is an addon to my previous question; I am trying to delete a specific row when the button is clicked, however everytime the button is clicked it deletes the next table row instead of itself. Here is what it looks like with a [video](https://streamable.com/uqn63a). The current code I am using to perform this action is:

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState([]);

const singleDelete = (d) => {
        const newArr = [...shop];
        const index = shop.findIndex((contact) => contact.id === d);
        newArr.splice(index, 1);
        setShop(newArr);
}

return (
        <div className="content">
         <Table>
            <tbody id="tbid">
                    
                      {(shop.map((s,i) => (
                        <tr key={`${s+i}`} id={i} value={`${i}Row`}>
                        <td>{i}</td>
                        <td>{profil[i]}</td>
                        <td>{s}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{acc[i]}</td>
                        <td>
                        <Button className="btn-round btn-icon" color="danger" size="sm" type="submit" onClick={singleDelete}>
                              <i className="icon-simple-delete"/>
                          </Button>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                      )))}
                    </tbody>    
         </Table>
        <div>
)
```

I have tried using
`setShop(shop.filter((_, index) => index !== d));`
But the results are still the same.

Comment: how does `d` have the value of the ID of the shop ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you don't pass the ID into the `singleDelete` function.

Change this:

`onClick={singleDelete}`

to this:

`onClick={ () => singleDelete(s.id) }`

And it would be nice to rewrite `singleDelete` function like @stoen recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using filter instead:

```
const singleDelete = (d) => {
    setShop(shop.filter((contact) => contact.id !== d));
}
```